# preg_match_all read from bottom up?

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I have this script which reads data from another website but i want the script to grab the data from bottom up rather then top down.

For example if the results are:

Result #1
Result #2
Result #3

I want to get #3 first, then 2 then 1. At the moment it gets 1 then 2 then 3.

Here is my script currently

```
$pattern = '#<a href="(.*?)" class="normalgrey font12px plain bold">(.*?)</a>#';
preg_match_all($pattern,$fileList,$match);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is the **array_reverse()** function on the $match results array :

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php

```
$reversed = array_reverse($match);
print_r($reversed);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$match = array_reverse($match);
```

Sometimes the array does not allow for this (thanks to Calimero's comment) which happens when you supply flags to preg_match_* such as PREG_PATTERN_ORDER to alter the structure of the $match array. If that is the case then use

```
$match[0] = array_reverse($match[0]);
```

That second one is for anyone reading this in the future that can't get it to work.

Comment: Happens when you supply flags to preg_match_* such as PREG_PATTERN_ORDER to alter the structure of the $match array.

Comment: Cheers for the update. It's always good to know the real route of the problem.

Comment: `PREG_PATTERN_ORDER` is the default behaviour of `preg_match*()` functions. Adding this option doesn't alter the structure of the result array.